# HTML - Body Rotation Affecting Fixed Elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform, fixed

I have a Javascript function which is used to shake the screen for about a second.

```
function shakeScreen() {
    var degrees = 0;
    var goal = 0;
    var goals = [5,-5,4,-4,3,-4,2,-2,1,-1,0];
    function frame() {
        if(goals[goal] < 0) {
            degrees -= 1;
        } else {
            degrees += 1;
        }
        get('body','tag');
        current[0].style.transform = 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)';
        if(degrees === goals[goal]) {
            goal += 1;
            if(goal === goals.length) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            }
        }
    }
    var intervalId = setInterval(frame,16);
}
```

Inside my HTML body, my first element has a fixed position. This element is a pop-up that displays messagers to users, and it has a fixed position so it appears in the same position on the screen if the end user has scrolled down or up the page. Here is a snippet of the HTML:

```
<body>
<div id='fade' onclick="fade('out')"><div id='alert'></div></div>
<!-- more unrelated content -->
```

Here is the CSS for the specified element above:

```
#fade {
    z-index: 2750;
    position: fixed; /*important*/
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    text-align: center;
}
#fade:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

When the Javascript function shakeScreen() is executed, the *fade* element gets misaligned and moves to the top of the body rather than remaining in the center of the end user's screen. Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/turkey3/ug9zx1d2/3/ Scroll down halfway and you'll see a button. Click that button to shake the screen. You'll notice a *split second* where the *fade* element starts appearing at the center of the screen, but then it moves to the top after it starts shaking. Also, to see how I want it to be, comment out the shakeScreen function that's inside the setup function and then run the code.

**Edit:** The *fade* element is simply a dark background. The *alert* element is a white box with the message that shows to the user.

Comment: Is an alert part of the document object model (DOM) body?  How about using a pre-existing div element within the body (change class name, etc to control hidden and displayed characteristics?) OUch. chrome dev tools show `<div id="alert ...` so that's not it.

Comment: "Alert" is simply the id of the div - nothing more. It's called so because on my website it "alerts" people a message - a prettier alternative to JS alert().

Comment: My bad.  I didn't see that at first. See my ouch note.  Not sure what's going on but when I change the body height to 300px, and button style margin-top to 100px, the whole things works perfectly!

Comment: That's because it's only a problem when you scroll down the page. The alert element shoots to the top of the page so if you already are at then top you won't notice a problem. But on my website the page size is about 3000px tall generally.

Comment: If you use CSS vertical centering techniques will that work to get where you want to go?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with "ventrical centering techniques".

Comment: `https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/`

Comment: Maybe if rather than rotating the body I simply wrap all the other elements in a div and rotate that div.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83160/discussion-between-zipzit-and-gwiddle-worker).

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

I found out the best method was, rather than rotating the *body* element, was to wrap all the other code insider a div and shake the division rather than the entire body. After that, the alert message properly showed in the center of the screen. Here is the fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/turkey3/ug9zx1d2/4/

Here is the HTML wrapped in the div:

```
<body>
<div id='fade' onclick="fade('out')"><div id='alert'></div></div>
<div id='shake'>
    <!-- more unrelated content -->
</div>
```

And updated JS:

```
function shakeScreen() {
    var degrees = 0;
    var goal = 0;
    var goals = [5,-5,4,-4,3,-4,2,-2,1,-1,0];
    function frame() {
        if(goals[goal] < 0) {
            degrees -= 1;
        } else {
            degrees += 1;
        }
        get('shake','id');
        current.style.transform = 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)';
        if(degrees === goals[goal]) {
            goal += 1;
            if(goal === goals.length) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            }
        }
    }
    var intervalId = setInterval(frame,16);
}
```